# TypeError: illegal invocation with JavaScript forEach function on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, foreach, typeerror, console.log

I am writing JavaScript higher-order function *forEach* which literally applies *action* as we loop through each element in the array:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        action(array[i]);
}
```

As I call forEach with action console.log to print out the array's elements, **TypeError: Illegal invocation** was returned:

```
forEach(["Henry", "Juliane","Robert"], console.log); 
// TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Puzzled, I tried creating function **print**, which does exactly what **console.log** does:

```
var print = function(value) {
    console.log(value);
};
```

Now, when I call forEach on the same array, with function print, I got the right answers.

```
forEach(["Henry", "Juliane","Robert"], print); 
// "Henry"
// "Juliane"
// "Robert"
```

Why was my first invocation illegal? Is it because I am using Chrome's JS console? The syntax looks fine, and print and console.log here do the same thing.

Comment: `this` inside `console.log` must point to `console`.

Comment: It probably has something to do with how arguments are processed...  A function works fine, but I'm not sure if typing `console.log` itself would be "legal."

Comment: Simpler example to reproduce the issue: `var log = console.log; log(42);`.

Comment: I see, thanks. It was an example used in Eloquent JavaScript (Chapter 5 on Higher-Order Functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net//05_higher_order.html). The in-line code for forEach which are identical to this one execute fine..